# Trying to incorporate pd.date_range into my python analysis

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm trying to plot the top 10 ATTACK TYPES for every PERPETRATOR GROUP that contains the string 'FBI' between all the DATES spanning 1970 & 1979.

I think I'm doing everything correctly minus the date part. Can anyone assist?

Here is my code:

```
df_1[(df_1['PERPETRATOR GROUP'].str.contains('FBI'))] & 
df_1[(df_1[DATE] > '1970-1-1') & df_1[(df_1[DATE] < '1979-12-31')
['ATTACK TYPE'].value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='barh')
```

Ok I think I may have solved it but I was wondering if anyone could proofread this and tell me if this is legit.

```
seventies_mask = (df_1['DATE'] > '1970-01-01') & (df_1['DATE'] < '1979-12- 
31')

df_1[(df_1['PERPETRATOR GROUP'].str.contains('FBI'))] & 
df_1.loc[seventies_mask]['ATTACK TYPE'].value_counts() 
[:10].plot(kind='barh')
```

Comment: can you show a snip your dataset head

Comment: @Naga Kiran Hi Naga - thank you for responding. I think I figured it outwith the above edits - do you mind taking a look?